# How to make \parshape work inside a tikz node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, parshape

Expected output (2nd line has 5mm more indent than 1st, 3rd and following lines have 5mm more indent than 2nd):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
  \parshape=3 5mm 40mm 10mm 35mm 15mm 30mm
  This is sentence 1. This is sentence 2. This is sentence 3. This is sentence 4. This is sentence 5.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Bad output (tikz):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path node[draw,text width=50mm]
      { \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
        \parshape=3 5mm 40mm 10mm 35mm 15mm 30mm
        This is sentence 1. This is sentence 2. This is sentence 3. This is sentence 4. This is sentence 5.
      };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just introduce `\par` command will solve the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path node[draw,text width=50mm]
      { \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
        \parshape=3 5mm 40mm 10mm 35mm 15mm 30mm
        This is sentence 1. This is sentence 2. This is sentence 3.
        This is sentence 4. This is sentence 5.\par
      };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you need a trailing `%` following `\setlength{}{}`.

Comment: @PeterGrill I have followed the tag what the user provided as MWE...anyhow, thanks...

Answer (score 8):

Put the text in a `\parbox`:

[image]

Also it appears that you can use the `font=` to set the `\parshape` and then it *just* works (although I am not sure that this is a good idea).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path node[draw,text width=50mm]
          {\parbox{\linewidth}{%
              \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
                \parshape=3 5mm 40mm 10mm 35mm 15mm 30mm
                This is sentence 1. 
                This is sentence 2. 
                This is sentence 3. 
                This is sentence 4. 
                This is sentence 5.%
          }%
      };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Code:

```
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path node[draw,text width=50mm, font={\parshape=3 5mm 40mm 10mm 35mm 15mm 30mm}]
       {%
            This is sentence 1. 
            This is sentence 2. 
            This is sentence 3. 
            This is sentence 4. 
            This is sentence 5.%
      };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```