# How to code custom nodes with texts accommodating a round tikz mindmap?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node, mindmaps, a0poster

```
\documentclass[portrait]{a0poster}
\usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amsthm, amssymb} % For math fonts, symbols and environments
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{dtklogos}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{metalogo}
 \usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees,shadows}
 \usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,shadows, arrows}
 \usepackage[hidelinks,pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}
 \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
 \usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
 \usetikzlibrary{shapes}
 \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
 \usetikzlibrary{timeline}
 \definecolor{airforceblue}{rgb}{0.36, 0.54, 0.66}
 \definecolor{bittersweet}{rgb}{1.0, 0.44, 0.37}
 \definecolor{applegreen}{rgb}{0.55, 0.71, 0.0}
  \newcommand*{\info}[4][16.3]{%
  \node [ annotation, #3, scale=0.65, text width = #1em,
      inner sep = 2mm ] at (#2) {%
  \list{$\bullet$}{\topsep=0pt\itemsep=0pt\parsep=0pt
   \parskip=0pt\labelwidth=8pt\leftmargin=8pt
   \itemindent=0pt\labelsep=2pt}%
   #4
   \endlist
    };
    }
    \begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{1\linewidth}
    \vspace{2.0cm}
    \huge\textbf{}\\ [0.5cm]% Title
    \end{minipage}%
     \vspace{30cm} 
     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     \centering
     \begin{tikzpicture}                    
     \begin{scope}[ yshift=-135cm, xshift=0cm, every annotation/.style = {draw,
                 fill = white, font = \Large}]                              
     \path[mindmap, scale=1.1, grow cyclic, concept color=black!90, text=white,
      every node/.style={concept, circular drop shadow},
      root/.style    = {concept,
      font=\large\bfseries\fontsize{28pt}{36pt}\selectfont, text width=10em},
      level 1 concept/.append style={font=\Large\bfseries,
      sibling angle=36,  level 2/.append style={sibling angle=30.0}, text width=9.1em,
      level distance=15em,inner sep=0pt},
      level 2 concept/.append style={font=\bfseries, level distance=10em, text width=4em},
      level 3 concept/.append style={sibling angle=30, font=\bfseries, level distance=6em, 
        text width=4em},
       ]
        node[root] {THE \\MINDMAP} [clockwise from=0]
        child[concept color=violet!80!black] {
        node[concept] (Blogs) {DNA Extraction} [clockwise from=20]
       child { node[concept]  (stutter){Organic}
        }
       child { node[concept] (exceptions){Inorganic}
       }
       child { node[concept]{FTA}} 
       }
       child[concept color=orange] {
       node[concept] (dropinparameters)
       {Quanti tation}
       [clockwise from=-15]
       child { node[concept] (LaTeXArtikel1)
         {Photo spect} }
      child { node[concept] (LaTeXArtikel2)
       {Quant. PCR}}
       child { node[concept] (blotting)
       {Blotting}
       } 
       }
       child[concept color=red!60!black] {
       node[concept](PCRparameters) {Ampli fication}
       [clockwise from=-55]
       child { node[concept] (threshold)
       {Multi plex}}
       child { node[concept] (variances)
       {Inhi bition}} 
       child { node[concept] (lsae)
       {Stutter}}
        }
       child[concept color=bittersweet] {
      node[concept] (popsettings2) {Electro\\phoresis}
       [clockwise from=270]
       child { node[concept] (Gel)
       {Gel}}
       child { node[concept] (Capillary)
       {Capil\\lary} }
        child { node[concept] (Artifacts)
        {Arti\\facts} }
         }
        child[concept color=blue] {
        node[concept] {Inter\\pretation}
        [counterclockwise from=180]
        child { node[concept] (ratios)
        {Frequent\\ist}} 
       child { node[concept] (shared)
         {Bayes\\ian}} 
        child { node[concept] (arti)
         {Mixtures}} 
         }
        child[concept color=purple!90!black] {
        node {Mito\\chondrial DNA} [counterclockwise from=145]
        child { node (pull-ups) {SNPs}} 
        child { node (inhibition) {Haplo\\types}}
        child {node (degradation) {Control\\Region} } 
        }
        child[concept color=green!40!black] {
         node[concept] (error) {Y Chromo\\some}
        [clockwise from=165]
        child { node[concept] (Haplotypes) 
         {Haplo\\types}} 
       child { node[concept] (Lineage)
        {Lineage}} 
        child { node[concept] (STRs)
        {STRs}}
          }
      child[concept color=red] {
       node[concept] (popsettings) {Population Settings}
       [clockwise from=125]
      child { node[concept] (alleledata)
      {Allele \\Data}}
     child { node[concept] (fst)
     {Fst Values} }
     child { node[concept] (soft)
      {Softwares} }
        }
     child[concept color=airforceblue] {
     node[concept] (humangenome) {Human Genome}
      [clockwise from=90]
      child { node[concept] (STRs)
      {STRs}}
      child { node[concept] (fst)
      {Repeats} }
       child { node[concept] (mt)
       {Mt DNA} }
        }
       child[concept color=applegreen] {
       node[concept] (humangenome) {DNA Degrdation}
       [clockwise from=50]
       child { node[concept] (STRs2)
       {Low Copy}}
       child { node[concept] (fst2)
       {Mini STRs} }
        child { node[concept] (mt2)
         {Causes} }
         };
         \end{scope}
         \end{tikzpicture}
         \end{document}
```

[image: mindmap needs a node around it]

Comment: Related: [Q675862](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/675862). A node shape will be complicated.